# Postgres: how can I aggregate a row to report the column name with the highest value?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

For each row in a postgres table, I'm trying to determine the name of the column with the highest value:

**input**

```
 row_id | type1 | type2 | type3 
--------+-------+-------+-------
 A      |     2 |    44 |     7
 B      |   321 |     5 |    73
 C      |   302 |   620 |     9
```

**desired output**

```
 row_id | max_type | max_value 
--------+----------+-----------
 A      | type2    |        44
 B      | type1    |       321
 C      | type2    |       620
```

This is similar to [this SQL Server question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598895/output-the-column-name-with-the-highest-value), but `CROSS APPLY` seems to [not be precisely related to anything in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472790/analogue-to-cross-apply).

I've tried this, but it traverses the entire table, not one row at a time:

```
SELECT
  unnest(ARRAY['type1','type2','type3']) AS max_type,
  unnest(ARRAY[type1,type2,type3]) AS max_value
FROM table
ORDER BY max_value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

What's the correct way to go about this in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON (row_id)` with `ORDER BY row_id, max_value DESC`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (row_id) row_id, max_type, max_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        row_id,
        unnest(ARRAY['type1','type2','type3']) AS max_type,
        unnest(ARRAY[type1,type2,type3]) AS max_value
    FROM a_table
    ) s
ORDER BY row_id, max_value DESC;

 row_id | max_type | max_value 
--------+----------+-----------
 A      | type2    |        44
 B      | type1    |       321
 C      | type2    |       620
(3 rows)
```

Comment: This is brilliant - though I have to admit I don't really understand WHY it works when no explicit `LIMIT 1` is used.